# What can I line a collectible card box with that is not felt or flocking?

Tags: material-selection, wood

I made a card box, for holding Magic cards, a while ago, and I lined it with felt. While that does look good all the plastic sleeves I use get caught on the material so it is difficult to put them away.

Flocking seems like a good idea as well but I am imagining loose bits getting into the cards and it bothers me. Yes, I have never actually flocked anything before, but even if it all adheres to the paint I find it hard to believe that it will never fleck off.

What can I choose to line a card box with? It has to be something that will allow the sleeved cards to move freely and stay in its place. Being decorative is secondary, if it matters.

Comment: What are the inside dimensions of the box, and how much clearance do you have between the plastic sleeves and the sides?

Answer (score 5):

You could take inspiration from old suitcases: these used either fabric (woven linen or cotton), or paper. (I actually suspect that they used bookbinding paper/cloth, more on that later.)

Reasonably sturdy paper would be easiest to handle - patterned wrapping paper from a craft store, maybe, or even a piece of wallpaper.

Fabric can be tricky (stretching, glue seeping), but a smooth, woven upholstery fabric is a reasonable option.

If you can get your hands on book cloth, that's definitely a great choice. It's fabric lined with paper, sold in sheets or rolls. Takes glue well, doesn't stretch or wrinkle, easy to cut in straight lines. The downside is that it can be expensive or hard to find, depending on your location.

Comment: Velvet might be a good choice for the fabric, has a luxurious feel and look.

Comment: @rebusB That would look good, but I think the pile (fuzz) would catch on the plastic sleeves just as much as felt. In that repect silk would be the best fabric choice, but silk is a pain to glue without seeping. It's actually easiest if you use wheat paste and saturate the silk completely, so it looks even in the end.

Answer (score 4):

Leave the wood bare.  Sand it smooth then finish it and finally add a thin coat of wax to make the card sleeves move more freely.

Comment: I think I like the look of bare wood anyway but I was curious to ask